# Memory game not revealing correct guesses

Tags: java

This program is a Domino memory game where you flip dominos until you make a correct guess where the correct dominos are supposed to stay revealed. However the problem is that while the game does work correctly the dominos do not stay revealed nor does the game end.

This is the code for my Domino Class
`

```
public class Domino {
    private int top, bottom;
    private boolean revealed;

    public Domino(int x, int y) {
        if (x > y) {
            top = y;
            bottom = x;
        } else {
            top = x;
            bottom = y;
        }
    }

    public int getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public int getBottom() {
        return bottom;
    }

    
    public boolean isRevealed() {
        if (revealed)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    
    public void setRevealed(boolean revealed) {
        this.revealed = revealed;
    }

  
    public boolean equals(Domino other) {
        if (top == bottom)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

Then here is the memory game class (called MemoryLane)

`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MemoryLane
{
    private Domino[] board;

    
    public MemoryLane(int max)
    {
        board = new Domino[(max * max) + max];

        int i = 0;
        for(int top = 1; top <= max; top++)
            for(int bot = 1; bot <= max; bot++)
            {
                // make new Domino(2x) +
                // save into array
                if(top <= bot)
                {
                    board[i] = new Domino(top, bot);
                    i++;
                    board[i] = new Domino(top, bot);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        shuffle();
    }

    
    private void shuffle()
    {
        int index;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = board.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            if (index != i)
            {
                Domino temp = board[index];
                board[index] = board[i];
                board[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean guess(int i, int k)
    {
        if(board[i] == board[k])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    
    public String peek(int a, int b)
    {
        String text = new String();
        text += ("[" + board[a].getTop()+ "] [" + board[b].getTop()+ "]\n");
        text += ("[" + board[a].getBottom()+ "] [" + board[b].getBottom()+ "]\n");

        return text;
    }
    
    public boolean gameOver() {

        int count = 0;

        for(int i=0; i< board.length; i++)
        {
            if(board[i].isRevealed())
                count ++;
        }

        return (count == board.length);
    }

 
    public String toString() {
        String text = new String();

        for(int i=0; i< board.length; i++)
        {
            if(board[i].isRevealed())
                text += ("[" + board[i].getTop()+ "] ");
            else
                text += ("[ ] ");
        }

        text += ('\n');

        for(int i=0; i< board.length; i++)
        {
            if(board[i].isRevealed())
                text +=  ("[" + board[i].getBottom()+ "] ");
            else
                text += ("[ ] ");
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

`
Then here is the driver (the driver was provided to me by a third party so it must work as it is presented and cannot be changed)

`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryLaneDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message = "Welcome to Memory Lane!" + "\n" +
                "Choose two indexes to reveal the corresponding dominoes." + "\n" +
                "If the dominoes match, they stay revealed." + "\n" +
                "Reveal all the dominoes to win the game!" + "\n";

        System.out.println(message);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        MemoryLane game = new MemoryLane(2);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(!game.gameOver())
        {
            System.out.println(game);

            System.out.print("First:  ");
            int first = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Second: ");
            int second = input.nextInt();

            game.guess(first, second);
            System.out.println(game.peek(first, second) + "\n");
        }

        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed = (stop - start) / 1000;

        System.out.println(game);

        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        System.out.println("Total time: " + elapsed + "s");
    }
}
```

`

I have tried using the methods in Domino like setRevealed and isRevealed in the guess method (for example when i try board.setRevealed = true or board.isRevealed = true), but it wont work and turns up red in IntelliJ. I can also not use any Stringbuilder uses (such as append) because it is outside of what has been covered in class.

When I say the game is working correctly, I mean that it outputs my choices like:

`

```
Welcome to Memory Lane!
Choose two indexes to reveal the corresponding dominoes.
If the dominoes match, they stay revealed.
Reveal all the dominoes to win the game!

[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
First:  1
Second: 3
[2] [2]
[2] [2]


[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
First:
```

`

However as you can see it is not revealing the correct guess, and even if I guess all of the Dominos correctly the game does not end.

Comment: Q: Have you stepped through your code in the IntelliJ debugger?  This is absolutely the fastest, most effective way to a) troubleshoot this problem, and - more importantly - b) check for OTHER possible issues you might not have discovered yet.  In particular, you want to set breakpoints wherever you're calling "setRevealed()": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: When do you call `setRevealed`?

Comment: `board[i] == board[k]` is also doing a memory location comparison and not evaluating the properties of the object.  You may want to do some research into how `equals` works in Java

Comment: @MadProgrammer

While writing my comment I realized I was writing the board[i].setRevealed wrong, when writing it correctly as:

`
```
 public boolean guess(int i, int k)
    {
        if(board[i].equals(board[k]))
        {
            board[i].setRevealed(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```
`
It only returns the first guess regardless of if it is true or not when the first guess is above 1.

Edit: I was wrong it seems like it will only return four of the numbers seemingly at random and with different indexes each time.

Comment: The `Domino.equals(Domino other)` method is suspect. It doesn't use the `other` parameter. Instead of `public boolean equals(Domino other)`, it could be `public boolean isDoubles ()`.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your original code, you were using `board[i] == board[k]` which is comparing memory address locations and not the object properties, instead, you should be using `board[i].equals(board[k])`.

In this case you need to override `equals` method of the `Domino` class in order to change how the comparison works, for example...

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 59 * hash + this.getTop();
    hash = 59 * hash + this.getBottom();
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Domino)) {
        return false;
    }
    final Domino other = (Domino) obj;
    if (this.getTop() != other.getTop()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getBottom() != other.getBottom()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's important to remember, if you override `equals` you should also override `hashCode` as they have an important relationship to each other.

You also never call `setRevealed`, which I guess should be done in `guess`

```
public boolean guess(int i, int k) {
    if (board[i].equals(board[k])) {
        board[i].setRevealed(true);
        board[k].setRevealed(true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        String message = "Welcome to Memory Lane!" + "\n"
                + "Choose two indexes to reveal the corresponding dominoes." + "\n"
                + "If the dominoes match, they stay revealed." + "\n"
                + "Reveal all the dominoes to win the game!" + "\n";

        System.out.println(message);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        MemoryLane game = new MemoryLane(2);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!game.gameOver()) {
            // This is just making it easier to cheat.
            System.out.println(game.debug());
            System.out.println(game);

            System.out.print("First:  ");
            int first = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Second: ");
            int second = input.nextInt();

            game.guess(first, second);
            System.out.println(game.peek(first, second) + "\n");
        }

        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed = (stop - start) / 1000;

        System.out.println(game);

        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        System.out.println("Total time: " + elapsed + "s");
    }

    public class Domino {
        private int top, bottom;
        private boolean revealed;

        public Domino(int x, int y) {
            if (x > y) {
                top = y;
                bottom = x;
            } else {
                top = x;
                bottom = y;
            }
        }

        public int getTop() {
            return top;
        }

        public int getBottom() {
            return bottom;
        }

        public boolean isRevealed() {
            return revealed;
        }

        public void setRevealed(boolean revealed) {
            this.revealed = revealed;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 59 * hash + this.getTop();
            hash = 59 * hash + this.getBottom();
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Domino)) {
                return false;
            }
            final Domino other = (Domino) obj;
            if (this.getTop() != other.getTop()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.getBottom() != other.getBottom()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MemoryLane {
        private Domino[] board;

        public MemoryLane(int max) {
            board = new Domino[(max * max) + max];

            int i = 0;
            for (int top = 1; top <= max; top++) {
                for (int bot = 1; bot <= max; bot++) {
                    // make new Domino(2x) +
                    // save into array
                    if (top <= bot) {
                        board[i] = new Domino(top, bot);
                        i++;
                        board[i] = new Domino(top, bot);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            shuffle();
        }

        private void shuffle() {
            int index;
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = board.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
                if (index != i) {
                    Domino temp = board[index];
                    board[index] = board[i];
                    board[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean guess(int i, int k) {
            if (board[i].equals(board[k])) {
                board[i].setRevealed(true);
                board[k].setRevealed(true);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public String peek(int a, int b) {
            String text = new String();
            text += ("[" + board[a].getTop() + "] [" + board[b].getTop() + "]\n");
            text += ("[" + board[a].getBottom() + "] [" + board[b].getBottom() + "]\n");

            return text;
        }

        public boolean gameOver() {

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                if (board[i].isRevealed()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return (count == board.length);
        }

        public String debug() {
            String text = new String();

            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                text += ("[" + board[i].getTop() + "] ");
            }

            text += ('\n');

            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                text += ("[" + board[i].getBottom() + "] ");
            }

            return text;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String text = new String();

            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                if (board[i].isRevealed()) {
                    text += ("[" + board[i].getTop() + "] ");
                } else {
                    text += ("[ ] ");
                }
            }

            text += ('\n');

            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                if (board[i].isRevealed()) {
                    text += ("[" + board[i].getBottom() + "] ");
                } else {
                    text += ("[ ] ");
                }
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

The problem was my equals method was comparing top to bottom which is why i was getting such weird results. I changed it to

```java
   public boolean equals(Domino other){
       return this.top == other.top && this.bottom == other.bottom
   }
```

and now it works perfectly fine thanks for all of the help guys!

Comment: So, be careful with this, `equals(Domino)` doesn't override the `Object#equals` which would be a more appropriate start point and provide a wider range support for things like `List` and `Map`.  You should also be checking for `null`, because your `equals` method has no idea of what it's been passed - think, self contained and isolated.